# Js serialize() and adding data into database

Tags: javascript, php, ajax

I grab data from form with

```
var form_data =  $('#form').serialize();
```

i get result for example 
name=bill&age=133&gender=male

then this data send with ajax to controller

```
 $.ajax({
                            type: "POST",
                            url: "<?php echo base_url().'admin/crud/change_table_data2'?>",
                            data: { 'form_data' : form_data},
                            dataType: "json",
                            success: function(response)
                            {  
                            alert(response);
                            } 
                    })
```

in controller i try this, and send data to model, where i try to insert data into database

```
parse_str($_POST['form_data'], $add_array);  //parse form inputa koji za koje je koriscenja js f-ja serialize()

            $this->load->model('Data');
            $query = $this->Data->ajax_add($add_array);
```

my problem is somehow when i use print_r($add_array) i get no result on page or success part in ajax, so i cant see structure of array, i cant figure it out where is error, can someone write me foreach for `name=bill&age=133&gender=male` array similar to this

```
public function ajax_add($add_array)
    { 
       foreach($add_array as $s)
       {
            foreach($s as $x)
            {
                (string)$data_sanitazed = htmlentities(mysql_real_escape_string($x));
                $data_insert = array('info' => $data_sanitazed);
                $query = $this->db->insert('ci_crud', $data_insert);  
            } 
       }
        return $query;             
    }
```

diffrence is here i only have one colum and later i added two more

Answer (score 0, accepted):

No you do not need to put it inside another parent holder. Use that serialized inputs directly:

```
var form_data = $('#form').serialize();
 $.ajax({
    type: "POST",
    url: "<?php echo base_url().'admin/crud/change_table_data2'; ?>",
    data: form_data, // you can use it directly (name=bill&age=133&gender=male)
    // dataType: "json", also commenting this worked for the OP as well.
    success: function(response) {  
        alert(response);
    } 
});
```

So in PHP, you can use them inside post, no need to use `parse_str()`:

```
$_POST['name'] // directly access them
$_POST['age']
$_POST['gender']
```

Comment: problem is because i put  dataType: "json",

Comment: ty just a comment json line in your answer